# Area51 duplicate account?

Tags: support, area-51, user-accounts

At Area51 I somehow ended up with duplicate accounts: o_O

http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/152164/michael-dibbets
http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/152166

These are both me. This happened after I wiped cookies and cleared cache in an attempt to see my name appear in the users list in the right for [OctoberCMS proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms).

Can someone merge these accounts so everything adds up properly?

For those who considered closing my question as a duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Error I get when trying to merge via "contact us" form on Stack Overflow:

> [image]

Errors I get when trying to merge via ["contact us" on Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/contact):

> [image]

(Area 51 itself doesn't have any Help Center of "contact us" form.)

Comment: Well, in theory you can try to fill the form [on Area 51 meta](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/contact) but I'm pretty sure it would fail as well.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uRRKmcQ.png

Comment: Huh! Well, this seals the deal then - and since Robert didn't close again and probably deleted my comment, guess he was convinced as well.